# json to dataframe: nested list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a json list which looks like

```
data = [{'entry':{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}}, 
   {'entry':{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}}, 
   {'entry':{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}}, 
   {'entry':{'points':20, 'month': 'june'}}]
```

How can I create a pandas dataframe out of this (I want to drop the entry field as it's reduntant)?

The following works but is incredibly slow (for large data)

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
json_normalize(data)
```

This is quicker but not as pandonic I think

```
pd.DataFrame([d['entry'] for d in data])
```

I feel that there must be a better solution. I've tried the following with no joy

```
json_normalize(data, ['entry'])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame((d['entry'] for d in data))`

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than your solution: `pd.DataFrame([d['entry'] for d in data])`. This is certainly not *un*pandonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel that there must be a better solution.

Define "better". Do you mean faster? There isn't, not for structures like this, no. List comprehensions are optimised to be even faster than their for-loop equivalents in almost every instance.

Do you mean something that looks nicer? I think a list comprehension looks quite nice, to be honest.

Is there a magic one-liner to automagically process data in this format? Yes! Sadly, you've already found it (`json_normalize`), and as you've discovered, is much slower than the list comp:

```
In [431]: data = data * 10000

In [432]: %timeit json_normalize(data)
1.3 s ± 19.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [433]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([d['entry'] for d in data])
63.2 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, no, there's isn't a better solution.

Comment: Better as in faster. Not sure why, but this surprised me a little. Thanks

Comment: @mark It shouldn't surprise you all that much. ;-) List comprehensions are implemented in _pure_ C code, and are _very_ fast if used right. OTOH, `json_normalize` is written in python, and is built to cater to a wide range of use cases. There's a lot more overhead in the latter case.